# In keras what is the result of model.predict() and problem with loaded model's prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

(Python 3.7, tensorflow 2.3, keras 2.4.3)

I made a classifier with resnet 50(with functional api in keras).
I trained, saved and loaded the model.
And I want to see the probability of the prediction with one picture so i used model.predict() method.

I thought the result of model.predict() is a probability of prediction but the result was like this

[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]]

The other problem is that result was wrong and the result was always same like that even when I tested with another pictures.

I want to know is there any other method to get the probability of prediction, why does my model always get same predictions and any problem with my code.

this code is for training and saving model

```
import  keras
from keras import models, layers
from keras import Input
from keras.models import Model, load_model
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import optimizers, initializers, regularizers, metrics
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Conv2D, Activation, Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D, Add
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
 
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

train_dir = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\deeplearning\아주대 고양이 판별기(resnet-18\data\trainset')
 
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, batch_size=16, target_size=(224, 224), color_mode='rgb')

# number of classes
K = 10

input_tensor = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), dtype='float32', name='input')
 
 
def conv1_layer(x):    
    x = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(3, 3))(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, (7, 7), strides=(2, 2))(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,1))(x)
 
    return x   
 
def conv2_layer(x):         
    x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), 2)(x)     
 
    shortcut = x
 
    for i in range(3):
        if (i == 0):
            x = Conv2D(64, (1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = Activation('relu')(x)
            
            x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = Activation('relu')(x)
 
            x = Conv2D(256, (1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')(x)
            shortcut = Conv2D(256, (1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')(shortcut)            
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            shortcut = BatchNormalization()(shortcut)
 
            x = Add()([x, shortcut])
            x = Activation('relu')(x)
            
            shortcut = x
 
        else:
            x = Conv2D(64, (1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = Activation('relu')(x)
            
            x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = Activation('relu')(x)
 
            x = Conv2D(256, (1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)            
 
            x = Add()([x, shortcut])   
            x = Activation('relu')(x)  
 
            shortcut = x        
    
    return x
 
def conv3_layer(x):        
    shortcut = x    
    
    for i in range(4):     
        if(i == 0):            
            x = Conv2D(128, (1, 1), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = Activation('relu')(x)        
            
            x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = Activation('relu')(x)  
 
            x = Conv2D(512, (1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')(x)
            shortcut = Conv2D(512, (1, 1), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')(shortcut)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            shortcut = BatchNormalization()(shortcut)            
 
            x = Add()([x, shortcut])    
            x = Activation('relu')(x)    
 
            shortcut = x              
        
        else:
            x = Conv2D(128, (1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = Activation('relu')(x)
            
            x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = Activation('relu')(x)
 
            x = Conv2D(512, (1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)            
 
            x = Add()([x, shortcut])     
            x = Activation('relu')(x)
 
            shortcut = x      
            
    return x

def conv4_layer(x):
    shortcut = x        
  
    for i in range(6):     
        if(i == 0):            
            x = Conv2D(256, (1, 1), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = Activation('relu')(x)        
            
            x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = Activation('relu')(x)  
 
            x = Conv2D(1024, (1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')(x)
            shortcut = Conv2D(1024, (1, 1), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')(shortcut)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            shortcut = BatchNormalization()(shortcut)
 
            x = Add()([x, shortcut]) 
            x = Activation('relu')(x)
 
            shortcut = x               
        
        else:
            x = Conv2D(256, (1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = Activation('relu')(x)
            
            x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = Activation('relu')(x)
 
            x = Conv2D(1024, (1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)            
 
            x = Add()([x, shortcut])    
            x = Activation('relu')(x)
 
            shortcut = x      
 
    return x

def conv5_layer(x):
    shortcut = x    
  
    for i in range(3):     
        if(i == 0):            
            x = Conv2D(512, (1, 1), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = Activation('relu')(x)        
            
            x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = Activation('relu')(x)  
 
            x = Conv2D(2048, (1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')(x)
            shortcut = Conv2D(2048, (1, 1), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')(shortcut)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            shortcut = BatchNormalization()(shortcut)            
 
            x = Add()([x, shortcut])  
            x = Activation('relu')(x)      
 
            shortcut = x               
        
        else:
            x = Conv2D(512, (1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = Activation('relu')(x)
            
            x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = Activation('relu')(x)
 
            x = Conv2D(2048, (1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)           
            
            x = Add()([x, shortcut]) 
            x = Activation('relu')(x)       
 
            shortcut = x                  
 
    return x
 
x = conv1_layer(input_tensor)
x = conv2_layer(x)
x = conv3_layer(x)
x = conv4_layer(x)
x = conv5_layer(x)
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
output_tensor = Dense(K, activation='softmax')(x)
 
resnet = Model(input_tensor, output_tensor)

resnet.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'rmsprop', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    
resnet.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch = 11, epochs = 50)



resnet_json = resnet.to_json()
with open("resnet.json", "w") as json_file :
    json_file.write(resnet_json)
print("saved model architecture")
    
resnet.save_weights('weights.h5')

print("saved weights")
```

and this is for loading the model and predicting

```
from keras.models import model_from_json, load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import Input
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image as pilimg


json_file = open("resnet.json", "r")
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
loaded_model.load_weights("weights.h5")


"""
loaded_model = load_model('resnet-50.h5')
"""


print("loaded model and weights")

x = pilimg.open(r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\deeplearning\아주대 고양이 판별기(resnet-18\test\test.jpg')
x = x.resize((224,224))
plt.imshow(x)
plt.show()
x = np.array(x)
x = np.reshape(x, (1, 224, 224, 3))


loaded_model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'rmsprop', metrics = ['accuracy'])

result = loaded_model.predict(x)
print(result)
#print(loaded_model.predict_proba(x))
#print(loaded_model.predict_classes(x))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a probability of prediction. In this case, it just happened that it predicted close to 100% to `class == np.argmax(result)`, and very close to 0 to the other classes.

In fact, you can infer that these are float numbers(probabilities) and not int, since they have a dot after them, e.g. `0. 1.`

Now if for all the predictions you get the same result, this is a problem with regard to the training(i.e. either your model may have overfitted and it predicts only one class or you do not apply the same proprocessing on the test images like you applied on the training images and you get incorrect results).

Comment: Thanks for answering, After reducing some epochs the result keep changed but they are still like [0.], [1.]s.

Comment: What are the metrics on training and validation?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what is 'metrics on training and validation'. Do you mean the accuracy when the train finished? And I don't have many data for this so I didn't use validation data, only train data and some test data..

Comment: Okay, so then for the training what is the accuracy for the last epoch?

Comment: First it was 50 epochs and 95% accuracy, for now, I changed to 30 epochs and have 65% accuracy and the result was like the comment.

Comment: I solved it. I trained with rescaled images (by 1./255) but didn't rescale when I test. Thank you.

Comment: Told you it must have come as a problem of test_preprocessing. Since you solved the problem could you please accept my answer as the solving one since it contains the solution to your problem. Thank you :D